# How to Write A Mutation Response Check

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

I am running a graphql mutation like this:

```
interface SignInReponse {
  loginEmail : {
    accessToken: string;
  }
}
const [login] = useMutation<SignInReponse>(LOGIN);
```

This is how the mutation looks like in the schema:

```
loginEmail(
  email: String!
  password: String!
): SignInResponse!
```

```
type SignInResponse {
  accessToken: String!
}
```

Now the login and everything works fine but I feel that the `interface SignInResponse` isnt actually doing anything.
For instance, I tried replacing my SignInResponse with this:

```
interface SignInReponse {
  users: {
   nodes: {
    id: string;
    firstHelloName:number;
    lastName: string;
    phoneNumber: string;
    email: string;
   }[]
  }
}
```

Clearly incorrect. But the login is still successful and no errors are shown. So what's the point?

Edit:
So this is how I am using the mutation:

```
const [login] = useMutation<SignInReponse>(LOGIN);

  let submitForm = (email: string, password: string) => {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
    login({
      variables: {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      },
    })
      .then(({ data }: ExecutionResult<SignInReponse>) => {
        dispatch({ type: "login", payload: data.loginEmail.accessToken })  
      })
```

Before `ExecutionResult<SignInReponse>`, I was just using `any`. However, now that I have changed the type, it gives me an error on `data` from `data.loginEmail.accessToken`:

```
var data: SignInReponse | null | undefined
Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.ts(2533)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding types to your code will not affect how your code executes. TypeScript has to be compiled to JavaScript in order to be executed, at which point any type information is stripped from your code anyway.

The "point" of providing a type for the response to your `useMutation` hook is to indicate the shape of the response returned by the mutation. When you execute the mutation, you'll do something like:

```
const { data } = await login()
```

By providing a type for the response, the type for `data` will be that type instead of `any`. If you attempt to access a property on `data` that isn't defined by the type, the TypeScript compiler will throw an error (and depending on the editor, you'll see the error in your editor too).

Comment: Makes sense! Could you see the updated qs? How can I fix the null issue? Is it because it's possible that the query might not return anything at all? In case the mutation is not successful. (for eg if password isn't correct)

Comment: Right, so you should make sure it's truthy before accessing any properties on it. By the way, you can [generate these type definitions](https://graphql-code-generator.com/) instead of writing them yourself.

Comment: It works now. If I try to access a property not defined in the interface, it throws an error. However, if I change the data type of ```accessToken```  to ```number``` in the interface, and try to access accessToken, it still works. Is that normal?

Comment: Yes, but if you try to call a String method like `trim` on it, it'll also throw.